# SmartGWT two modules one datasource

Tags: datasource, smartgwt, hsqldb

I am having a hell of a time sharing a datasource across two GWT modules.  Is there some trick I am missing?

I have tried about everything.  I would post something, but not sure it would help as I have changed it so much.  Any guidance/tutorial on how a datasource can be shared between two GWT modules?

Here is the issue I have.  One module will add data to the source, that source goes into an HSQLDB for persistence.  This works fine.  However the second module never picks up the data added.  If I try to show the data from the first module, I get no problems.

I am using "DataSource.get("DS_Name")" in both modules.

In each HTML I added this line: "[script src="FirstModuleName/sc/DataSourceLoader?dataSource=DS_Name"][/script]"

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is SmartGWT, in the html for your second module, make sure that the isomorphicDir="FirstModuleName/sc". That should give it the correct path to the dataSourceLoader